# Randomly distribute a seed spot to 128 teams using php

Tags: php, algorithm

I have 128 teams participating in a single-elimination tournament. I want to achieve the following:

1. By pressing a button be able to put these teams randomly facing each other (meaning 64 matches)
2. Understand if you win where you will be placed in the next game and who you will face

Currently my database has these tables:

- teams (list of 500 teams)
- tournaments (this tournament for e.g. is id = 1)
- participation (list of 128 teams that want to play in tournament id = 1)
- match (this is where I need to somehow add team 1 and team 2 randomly and also know where in the bracket they stand)

At the moment for the match table I have:

1. id
2. tournament_id
3. round (where a 128 team tournament can go up to 7 rounds: 128 / 64 / 32 / 16 / 8 / 4 / 2
4. game (meaning on the bracket where it stand, was thinking this way I can define Round 2 has Game 1 and Game 2 of Round 1 playing each other etc. not sure this is a good idea)
5. team1_id
6. team2_id
7. team1_score
8. team2_score
9. winner_team_id
10. status

Does anyone have experience on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all rows from `teams` in a random order:

```
SELECT * FROM teams ORDER BY RAND()
/* Or: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/955/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-a-random-ordering */
```

With PHP: for every two rows you retrieve, insert a row into `match`, using the first team's `teams.id` as `team1_id` and the 2nd team's `teams.id` as `team2_id`, and the other fields filled out accordingly.